# Testing a react component using custom hooks with crud operations functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a functional component (AddTodo). AddTodo is using a custom hooks which is returning todoList, addItemInTodoList and other functions. I'm mocking the custom hook and using mockResolvedValueOnce to set the todoList and other functions. Is this the right approach to test react component using custom hook.

Here is my AddTodo component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useTodoList from '../hooks/useTodoList';
import Button from '../Components/button';
import Input from '../Components/input';

function AddTodo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const { todoList, addItemInTodoList } = useTodoList();
  const [todoText, setTodoText] = useState('');

  const handleTodoTextChange = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter') {
      handleAddItemClick();
      return;
    };
    setTodoText(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAddItemClick = async () => {
    let data = {
      key: todoList.length + 1,
      text: todoText,
      date: new Date().toLocaleString()
    };
    const result = await addItemInTodoList(data);
    if (result) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col w-25'>
      <h2>Add Todo Item</h2>
      <div className='flex'>
        <Input placeholder='Write something' value={todoText} onChange={handleTodoTextChange} onKeyPress={handleTodoTextChange} />
        <Button type='primary' value='Add' onClick={handleAddItemClick} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddTodo;
```

Here is my useTodo custom Hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useTodoList(todoItemKey) {
  const CACHE_NAME = "todo-list";
  const ENDPOINT = "https://localhost:3000";

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const [selectedTodoItem, setSelectedTodoItem] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const todoItem = todoList.find(item => item.key === parseInt(todoItemKey));
    setSelectedTodoItem(todoItem);
  }, [todoList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTodoList = async () => {
      try {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const response = await cache.match(ENDPOINT);

        if (!response) {
          return;
        }

        const responseBody = await response.json();
        setTodoList(responseBody);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("getToken error:", { error });
      }
    };
    getTodoList();
  }, []);

  const addItemInTodoList = async (data) => {
    const updatedTodoList = [...todoList, data]
    try {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      const responseBody = JSON.stringify(updatedTodoList);
      const response = new Response(responseBody);
      await cache.put(ENDPOINT, response);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("saveToken error:", { error });
      return false;
    }
  };

  const updateItemInTodoList = async (data) => {
    let updatedTodoList = todoList.filter(item => item.key !== data.key);
    updatedTodoList = [...updatedTodoList, data];
    updatedTodoList = updatedTodoList.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
    try {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      const responseBody = JSON.stringify(updatedTodoList);
      const response = new Response(responseBody);
      await cache.put(ENDPOINT, response);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("saveToken error:", { error });
    }
  };

  const deleteItemInTodoList = async (todoItemKey) => {
    const updatedTodoList = todoList.filter(item => item.key !== todoItemKey);
    try {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      const responseBody = JSON.stringify(updatedTodoList);
      const response = new Response(responseBody);
      await cache.put(ENDPOINT, response);
      setTodoList(updatedTodoList);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("saveToken error:", { error });
    }
  };

  return { todoList, addItemInTodoList, updateItemInTodoList, deleteItemInTodoList, selectedTodoItem, setSelectedTodoItem };
}
```

Here is my AddTodo test

```
import { fireEvent, getByText, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import useTodoList from '../hooks/useTodoList';
import AddTodo from '../Pages/AddTodo';

jest.mock('../hooks/useTodoList');

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

test('should render add todo page', () => {
  useTodoList.mockResolvedValueOnce({ todoList: [], addItemInTodoList: () => { }, updateItemInTodoList: () => { }, deleteItemInTodoList: () => { }, selectedTodoItem: {}, setSelectedTodoItem: () => { } });
  const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <AddTodo />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const input = getByPlaceholderText(/write something/i);
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'Todo Item 1'} });

  const btn = getByText(/add/i);
  fireEvent.click(btn);

  expect(addItemInTodoList).toBeCalledWith(/todo item 1/i);
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is there any error? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: Getting this error

console.error Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'todoList' of '(0 , _useTodoList.default)(...)' as it is undefined.]

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'todoList' of '(0 , _useTodoList.default)(...)' as it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mockResolvedValueOnce` to be `mockResolvedValue`.

```js
test('should render add todo page', () => {
  useTodoList.mockResolvedValue({ todoList: [], addItemInTodoList: () => { }, updateItemInTodoList: () => { }, deleteItemInTodoList: () => { }, selectedTodoItem: {}, setSelectedTodoItem: () => { } });
  
  // ...
});
```

When the component state updates, it causes it to rerender which calls `useTodoList` again, but your test had only allowed it to return the mocked value once, returning `undefined` on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are testing a component that is strongly related to the custom hook you shouldn't mock it, you must to test the actual behavior of the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).